# Reading and writing to console in Java

Tags: java, class, console

What is the most efficient class to use to read from and write to console in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 1.6 has a [Console](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) class that simplifies some things. In general, System.out and Scanner on top of System.in are usually enough.

Answer (score 1):

Like [System](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html).{out,in}?

Answer (score 1):

[BufferedReader](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and [BufferedWriter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) are the most efficient means of writing to and reading from the console, as well as any file. However, they are relatively difficult to use.

[Scanner](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) provides an alternative to retrieving input from the command line, and is much easier to use than BufferedReader.

Answer (score 1):

If you are printing log messages in an application, should use a logging API (log4j or whatever). You then specify which levels (debug, info, warn, ...) print on the console per class.

Logging tends to slow things down dramatically in my experience - so don't log within a tight loop (unless that logging level is typically off in production).