# Trying to read from the console in Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have just started learning Java with IntelliJ IDE.  I know a bit C# so the logic makes some sense, however there is one thing so far I couldn't get over it.

How do I read from the console? In C#, you could easily read what the human typed into it, using `Console.ReadLine()`.  In Java,  `System.console().readLine();` does not work for me and throws a `NullPointerException`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Look into the `Scanner` class, it should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: First result for googling last words from title of your question: "read from console JAVA" gives: [Java: How to get input from System.console()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644415/java-how-to-get-input-from-system-console). Also `System.console().readLine();` works fine for me (if I run my code via console, outside of IDE). We need to see your code and know how are you using it and what exception you are getting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading and writing to console in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746181/reading-and-writing-to-console-in-java)

Answer (score 87):

NOTE: problem doesn't appear when we run your code *from* console/terminal via `java [options] [MainClass]` so if this is valid solution for you you can stop reading here. Rest of this answer is for people who are using some IDEs to run their code.

### Problem

Most IDEs are using `javaw.exe` instead of `java.exe` to run Java code (see image below).

Difference between these two programs is that `javaw` runs Java code *without association with current terminal/console* (which is useful for GUI applications), and since there is no associated console window `System.console()` returns `null`. Because of that `System.console().readLine()` ends up as `null.readLine()` which throws `NullPointerException` since `null` doesn't have `readLine()` method (nor any method/field).

But just because there is no associated console, it doesn't mean that we can't communicate with `javaw` process. This process still supports standard input/output/error streams, so IDEs process (and via it also we) can use them via `System.in`, `System.out` and `System.err`.

This way IDEs can have some tab/window and let it *simulate* console.

For instance when we run code like in Eclipse:

```
package com.stackoverflow;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("hello world");
        System.out.println(System.console());
    }

}
```

we will see as result

[image]

which shows that despite `javaw.exe` not having associated console (`null` at the end) IDE was able to handle data from standard output of the `javaw` process `System.out.println("hello world");` and show `hello world`.

## General solution

To let user pass information to process use standard input stream (`System.in`). But since `in` is simple `InputStream` and `Stream`s are meant to handle *binary* data it doesn't have methods which would let it easily and properly read data as text (especially if encoding can be involved). That is why `Readers` and `Writers` ware added to Java.

So to make life easier and let application read data from user as text you can wrap this stream in one of the `Reader`s like `BufferedReader` which will let you read entire line with `readLine()` method. Unfortunately this class doesn't accept `Streams` but `Reader`s, so we need some kind of *adapter* which will simulate Reader and be able to translate bytes to text. But that is why `InputStreamReader` exists.

So code which would let application read data from input stream could look like

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Hello. Please write your name: ");
String name = br.readLine();
System.out.println("Your name is: "+name);
```

### Preferred/simplest solution - Scanner

To avoid this *magic* involving converting Stream to Reader you can use `Scanner` class, which is meant to read data as text from Streams and Readers.

This means you can simply use

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
//...
String name = scanner.nextLine();
```

to read data from user (which will be send by console simulated by IDE using standard input stream).

Comment: If one is trying to use `Console.readPassword()`, the fact that most IDEs don't supply a `Console` is a killer. `java.io.InputStream`, `java.io.Reader`, `java.io.Console`, and `java.util.Scanner` all descend directly from `java.lang.Object` and have no interfaces in common.

Comment: Interestingly, `java.exe` provides `System.console()!=null` when ran from the command line, but provides `System.console()==null` whan ran from the Eclipse IDE (tried with Oracle JDK9/JDK10 and Eclipse Neon3)

Comment: I was getting this error: `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found`. The solution was run the main class instead of a gradle task

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the `Console` object requires a valid tty provided by an operating system, but IntelliJ IDEA output window does not provide one. It's not very trivial to do this in OS-independent way. Not only IntelliJ IDEA is affected. You cannot use `System.console()` in jshell as well:

```
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 17.0.6
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> System.console()
$1 ==> null

jshell>
```

In Java 20, this issue was partially addressed. Now, you can add a VM option `-Djdk.console=jdk.internal.le`. Go to 'Edit Run/Debug configurations', then Modify Options, Add VM Options and type it there. After that the `System.console()` will work inside IDE. It will be hooked to `System.in` which IDE already intercepts.

Note that this solution is undocumented and unsupported, so may not work in future Java versions. You can find more information in this [JDK issue](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8297226).

Answer (score 0):

If you realy need to Console object you can compile your class from command line. Firstly in my java file first statement is `package com.inputOutput;`

Go in your project "`src`" folder and compile it like : "`javac com/inputOutput/Password.java`" '`com`' and '`inputOutput`' are folder(package). Run your class file in `src` folder
`java com.inputOutput.Password`". It had worked work for me.

Answer (score 0):

**You could use an Jframe.**

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("titile");

// prompt the user to enter their code
String code = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "promt here");
```

Comment: How would one handle the input that's been given?

Answer (score 0):

I abstracted it out, so when running in an IDE, it will use the scanner, but when running from the command line, it'll use the console:

```java
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.Scanner;
    
public class UserInputReader {
  private final Console console;
  private final Scanner scanner;

  public UserInputReader() {
    console = System.console();
    scanner = console == null ? new Scanner(System.in) : null;
  }

  public String readLine() {
    return console != null ? console.readLine() : scanner.nextLine();
  }
    
  public String readPassword() {
    return console != null ? String.valueOf(console.readPassword()) : scanner.nextLine();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I start a terminal from my project in intellij then I type:

```bash
$ java -cp target/classes org.enricogiurin.ocp17.ch14.UserInput
```

Where `UserInput` is the class whose `main` uses the `java.io.Console`.

I know it's not the expected solution, in fact I have written that it's a workaround.

Answer (score -3):

`java.util.Scanner` API is what you are looking for.

Comment: Any explanations about why Scanner is what OP should use? What about other alternatives like BufferedReader? Also `System.console()` will also work if it is used properly.

Comment: Scanner API is a very simple API for reading the console inputs. It is very easy to get a hang of it, esp for the beginners. To start using the BufferedReader API, user should be aware of quite a few java.io related interfaces and the exact differences among them. It takes some time to get a hang of it and appreciate it. At least, that is what happened to me when there was no Scanner API, before java-1.5

Comment: There's another answer here explaining scanner in detail with example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26473083/6693304