# Can't compile. Error message

Tags: java, string, variables

I am trying to get an input from console, assign it to a string variable. Then I'd like to concatinate it with another variable. Provided if the user enters the right character each time, soon it'll make up a word. Once this word matches the desired one the loop stops.
Need your help though.

```
public class expl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String consatinate = "a";
        String needed = apple;
        while (!consatinate.equals(needed)) {
            System.out.println("Enter a letter");
            String input = System.console().readLine();
            consatinate = consatinate.concat(input);        
            System.out.println(consatinate);
        }
    }
}
```

Error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem: apple cannot be resolved to a variable at
>   expl.main(expl.java:6)

Comment: What is the error you are facing? Also what is `apple` (you seem to know how to create String literals since you already created one - `"a"` -  so did you perhaps forgot to surround it with `"`)?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 apple cannot be resolved to a variable

 at expl.main(expl.java:6)
sorry should have given it

Comment: Don't post important informations like error messages as comment. Instead put it in question using [edit] option (placed below your post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple is a literal string, so it should have quotations around it:

```
public class expl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String consatinate = "a";
        String needed = "apple";
        while (!consatinate.equals(needed)) {
            System.out.println("Enter a letter");
            String input = inputScanner.nextLine();
            consatinate = consatinate.concat(input);        
            System.out.println(consatinate);
        }

        inputScanner.close();
    }
}
```

I would also asume that "consatinate" should be named concatenate, but that's just a guess.

Comment: after correcting apple it says Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at expl.main(expl.java:9) And I know about spelling, I did it in purpose because it's just a variable name. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @HonestLearner that is different problem which deserves different question. But to avoid it take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470972/trying-to-read-from-console-java/26473083#26473083

Comment: Your problem with the null pointer is related to the question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104254/java-io-console-support-in-eclipse-ide

However, I have updated the answer for you to use a Scanner.

Comment: If it works for you, please remember to mark it as the answer by clicking the green tick - i'd much appreciate it.

Comment: If I had required reputation.))))))))))) Not this time unfortunately.

Comment: Oh how stack overflow robs me :D. Oh well, glad it helped :).

Comment: Sure than, but I can't see the green tick nor accept a question. Come on it's almost there)))

Comment: @HonestLearner You don't accept question, but answer :)

Comment: :) got it. Welcome to stack overflow.