# Java : How to read password from file?

Tags: java, console, passwords

I am using `System.console()` in order to read user password.

My code:

```
    Console console = System.console();
    if (console == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No console is available for input");
    }

    System.out.print("Enter the password: ");
    String password = new String(console.readPassword());
```

It's working fine when I am running it straightforward (from `Redhat`).

The problem is when I try to read the password from a text file:

`java -jar my_jar.jar < password.txt`

I get :

> No console is available for input.

How can I solve it ?

Comment: This sounds like a known bug/problem: System.console returns null. For information and possible workarounds see the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203646/system-console-returns-null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is expected. Quote from `java.io.Console`:

> Whether a virtual machine has a console is dependent upon the
> underlying platform and also upon the manner in which the virtual
> machine is invoked.  If the virtual machine is started from an
> interactive command line **without redirecting the standard input and
> output streams** then its console will exist and will typically be
> connected to the keyboard and display from which the virtual machine
> was launched.

For a possible solution without using `Console` you can read this answer [Trying to read from the console in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470972/trying-to-read-from-console-java/26473083#26473083).

You can keep using console if it is present and fail back to `BufferedReader`/`Scanner` if not.

Comment: Thanks, But i want to use the password obfuscation option java console provides.

Comment: You can keep using console if it is present and fail back to BufferedReader/Scaner if not. I dont understand how you can use 'password obfuscation option java console provides' if you have no console.

Comment: I don't want to use BufferedReader/Scaner because then i am in a risk that the user will set the password without obfuscation. Anyway, You are probably right and there is no solution. I will add an option to send the password in a text file.