# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at revArr.main(revArr.java:6) in InelliJ IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, null

I'm getting the following error while running the program in IntelliJ IDE. It's a simple program which takes input from cmd and prints it. When i run it through cmd it works fine but dosen't work on intelliJ

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   revArr.main(revArr.java:6)

```
public class revArr
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Using Console to input data from user
        String name = System.console().readLine();

        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend reading the [JavaDocs for `System.console`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console--)

Comment: Maybe you can find you > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470972/trying-to-read-from-the-console-in-java

Comment: this works if i run the program through cmd but dosen't if i run it through intelliJ IDE. @MadProgrammer @

Comment: That's because there is no `Console` attached