# ar.readLine not reading a input from user?

Tags: java, io, console

Summary
1. I am import java.io.console,i am not getting any error in my code,
    code is correct, I thought, It's getting some error in eclipse
    software... Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException   at
loops.Escapey.main(Escapey.java:9)
```

Coding:

```
package loops;

import java.io.Console;
public class Escapey {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Console ar = System.console(); // creating a new object for console

    String name = ar.readLine("how old are you ?"); //reads a user input 
    System.out.printf("%s - pretty age",name);
}
}
```

Ouput :
 - I except the output  how old are you ??  18 18 - pretty age
   But the actual output is getting error... Exception in thread "main"
   java.lang.NullPointerException   at loops.Escapey.main(Escapey.java:9)

Comment: why don't you use the Scanner class to get your input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How to get input from System.console()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644415/java-how-to-get-input-from-system-console).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to read from the console in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470972/trying-to-read-from-the-console-in-java)

Comment: seriously, please proof read and format your question. In its current state it's weird

Comment: `ar` is `null`. Use `Scanner` with method `nextInt()`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running this into some IDE. Since `System.console` returns the attached console, if you run it into IDE, it will return NULL. The better approach is to use Scanner class. If you really want to use `System.console`, you will have to test it on some console. If on Mac, run the terminal. On Linux any of the terminal apps would work.

Answer (score 0):

If we run this in IDE (Intellij), it is throwing null pointer exception. Since this is related to console, I tried to execute this in command line and it works fine.

Execute these steps in terminal or command line and it will work

```
1) javac Escapey.java
2) java Escapey
```