# Getting user input outside of App Class in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to write a program that requires user input of a file path. Using the thread linked below (and setting VM options in Run-> Edit Configurations) I was able to get it to work when I asked for input in my App class. It does not work when I try to ask for input in my object that controls the flow of the rest of the program. I have a feeling it's pretty simple considering I'm already half way there but I couldn't find threads that address my specific issue.

[Trying to read from the console in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470972/trying-to-read-from-the-console-in-java)

Comment: save the user input that does work into a variable?

Comment: Well I am just never prompted for input in the console within Intellij like I am when that command is in App

Comment: correct , the settings in IntelliJ won't behave the same on command line. But you want the app to handle user input the same for both?

Comment: Are you able to provide the code that you are having problems with? This will help others who might try to help you as it will enable them to recreate the problem as you are experiencing. Please refer to
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)